# comboboxes in Windows API programming

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to display  a combobox window as you can see I  set `hWndComboBox` as my second window and I am using `ShowWindow()` function and it does not really show anything when I compile and run the code? What should I add more?

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstace, LPSTR lpCommand, int nCmdLine)
{
    HWND window;
    int xpos = 100;            // Horizontal position of the window.
    int ypos = 100;            // Vertical position of the window.
    int nwidth = 200;          // Width of the window
    int nheight = 200;         // Height of the window
    HWND hwndParent =  window; // Handle to the parent window


    MSG message;
    WNDCLASSEX wndClass;

    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.style = 0;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = wndCll;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = classNoOne;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYMENU);
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PENGUIN_ICON));
    wndClass.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PENGUIN_ICON), IMAGE_ICON, LR_DEFAULTSIZE, LR_DEFAULTSIZE, 0);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW-1);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wndClass)){
        printf("No wndclass");
    }
    window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, classNoOne, "Start Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1000, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
        //create the window
    HWND hWndComboBox = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, "name of the combobox",  CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE , xpos, ypos, nwidth, nheight, hwndParent, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    TCHAR Planets[9][10] = {
        TEXT("MERCURY"), TEXT("VENUS"), TEXT("Terra"), TEXT("MARS"), TEXT("JUPITER"), TEXT("SATURN"), TEXT("URANUS"), TEXT("NEPTUNE"), TEXT("PLUTO")
    };
    //these are the list elements
    TCHAR A[16];
    int k = 0;
    memset(&A, 0, sizeof(A));
    //allocate memory
    for(k = 0; k<=8; k+=1){
    strcpy(A, (TCHAR *)Planets[k]);
      SendMessage(hWndComboBox,(UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,(WPARAM) 0,(LPARAM) A);
    }
    SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)2, (LPARAM)0);
    ShowWindow(hWndComboBox, nCmdLine);
   //ShowWindow(window, nCmdLine);
    if(window == NULL){
        printf("window is NULL");
    }

    while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
            if(!IsDialogMessage(dialogSmall, &message)){
                TranslateMessage(&message);
                DispatchMessage(&message);
            }
    }
    return message.wParam;
}
```

Comment: "doesnt really show anything"? What does it show?

Comment: but mainly, why write a windows gui app in C. Its a terrible choice

Comment: only the console appears, why is it a terrible choice? I can create windows and dialog boxes with C but since i am new i am having trouble with the combobox

Comment: also you need to check that the function you call work. Look at the return of CreateWondwEx etc. Call GetLAstError when needed

Comment: @pm100: Writing a Windows GUI application in C is probably the *best* way to learn Windows API programming. And knowing the Windows API is a prerequisite for using **any** other framework, Qt, MFC, Windows Forms, etc.

Comment: @pm100: Besides, there *is* a UI designer built into Visual Studio for a regular desktop GUI application (see [Resource Editors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-editors)). If you don't want to use Visual Studio, you could still author a resource script in a text editor, similar to XAML, but less verbose and not as powerful either.

Comment: If Jack wants to learn to use win32 raw API I totally agree. If he has a desire to write an app to do something with planets then its a bad plan.

Comment: @IInspectable but still pm100 has a point, I really rarely can find resources for WINAPI except MSDN, also it is kind of hard for me to understand code sometimes from MSDN, that's probably why I am having a problem with making an easy combobox,

Comment: @pm100 Whenever I look up C code example always C# appears but I want to learn C and not c#

Comment: @JackDelson if your aim is to learn C for Windows GUI programming, then for sure thats what you have to do. Warning - its not easy. I have been writing C and windows code for 25 years. I would never, ever voluntarily use C to write a GUI app. If you want to just learn C - dont write win32 gui apps

Comment: Is the "Start Window" displayed? Could you give us a screen shot? BTW: `wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW-1);`: You should use PLUS one instead of MINUS, but I'm afraid this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I found the problem, the codes must run inside of `LRESULT CALLBACK wnd()` function  with `switch(message){}` `case WM_CREATE:`

Comment: @JackDelson: Your problem is, that you think this should be easy. It isn't. It's not the type of code that fits inside a *"Teach yourself [...] in 21 minutes"* book. Here is a quick introduction in the MSDN ([Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx)). If you want to become proficient, you need Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: @pm100: `TCHAR Planets[9][10]` strongly indicates, that this is a toy project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming languages do not work like mathematics.  In mathematics you can say x = y;  and then say y = 5;  and then you can infer that x must be 5.

In programming languages however, when you say `HWND hwndParent =  window;` then `hwndParent` takes the value that `window` had ***at the moment of the assignment***, so if you later actually initialize `window` with `window = ...` you cannot expect the value of `hwndParent` to suddenly become meaningful.  It will stay uninitialized, since `window` was uninitialized at the time of the assignment.

Hint: if you have been able to do `HWND hwndParent =  window;` when `window` was uninitialized, this means that you received no warning about it.  Which in turn means that you have not configured your compiler to issue warnings when you do things like that.  Do not try to program without warnings.  You will never accomplish much this way.

Comment: I've put the `HWND hwndParent = window;` statement under the the function of `CreateWindowEx()` ,  I still can't see a window, I think I am having problems with the syntax maybe